# How to remove \r \n and other escape sequences in a string

Tags: c#, wpf, string

I have a string variable that I define as

```
String keyRight = new TextRange(rtb_KeyRight.Document.ContentStart, rtb_KeyRight.Document.ContentEnd).Text;
```

where rtb_KeyRight is a wpf richtextbox

But when I debug my code, the escape sequences \r\n are added to my string.

Doing this does not work:

```
keyRight.Replace("\r\n", "");
```

Any ideas?

Basically I'm just extracting the contents of the richtextbox and putting it in a string.

Comment: Have you tried `keyRight = keyRight.Replace(...);` The replace function does not modify the string it is on it returns the modified string.

Comment: thank you! forgot that fundamental rule!

Comment: Yes I just did this, thanks for reminding BTownTKD!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
keyRight = keyRight.Replace("\r\n", "");
```

Comment: +1. Also it is strange to remove "new lines" from multiline text (especially replacing with empty string not even whitespace). Hopefully it is still just an issue with just debug display showing escaped "\r\n" in immediate/watch window after all...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: That was my first thought. They're just newlines from the RichTextBox, and if viewed through the debugger's text display, I'd bet Mikk wouldn't see them. When you just hover over the string, you do, because the tooltip doesn't interpret it as a newline.

Comment: Hmm those are interesting thoughts ALexei and Chris.